# drupal2dupal migration add a default taxonomy term

Tags: 7, migrations

I want all of my imported data to have a default taxonomy term, since the source doesnt have this taxonomy term .  I have adde the tid of the taxonomy term in the UI as attached, but the content is being imported without this taxonoy term  . What am i doing wrong? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by typing in the name of the Taxonomy term , not the tid next to the field i wanted to import